# Storybook Canvas: 'ReferenceError: react is not defined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, storybook

Newbie to Storybook here.

I'm trying to integrate Storybook into my Gatsby front end. However, when trying to preview the test components in Storybook Canvas I get the following error:

react is not defined
ReferenceError: react is not defined
at react-dom/client (http://localhost:6006/main.iframe.bundle.js:1970:18)
at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:339:21)
at **webpack_require**.t (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:106:38)

[image]

I'm able to see the component preview in Storybook Docs but not in Storybook Canvas.

Link to repository:
https://github.com/akarpov91/gatsby-tutorial

Answer (score 16):

If you use new versions of Storybook, it uses SWC compiler by default and you need to change config a little bit. [enter link description here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configure/compilers#the-swc-compiler-doesnt-work-with-react)

```js
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions'
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
    options: {
      builder: {
        useSWC: true
      }
    }
  },
  swc: () => ({
    jsc: {
      transform: {
        react: {
          runtime: 'automatic'
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag'
  }
}
```

Comment: Best answer, should be the validated one

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following snippet in your `main.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  babel: async (options) => ({
    ...options,
    presets: [
      ...options.presets,
      [
    '@babel/preset-react', {
      runtime: 'automatic',
    },
        'preset-react-jsx-transform'
      ],
    ],
  }),
};
```

Apparently, `@storybook/react` adds `@babel/preset-react` without `runtime: 'automatic'` property

Comment: Thanks Ferran. I've added the snippet you shared, but i'm still getting the same error as before. I've updated the repo with your snippet.

Comment: It doesn't work. Seems like babel config does nothing whatsoever. Neither presets nor plugins help with this issue. 
But answer of @y0na24, about swc options, does work.

Comment: This did indeed work for me. Thank you Ferran. If you are using React + babel then use this. Otherwise, use the SWC setup.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, try copying this into your `.storybook/main.js` config. Hope this works for you too.

```
module.exports = {
  // You will want to change this to wherever your Stories will live
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: ["@storybook/addon-links", "@storybook/addon-essentials"],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [/node_modules\/(?!(gatsby)\/)/]

    // Use installed babel-loader which is v8.0-beta (which is meant to work with @babel/core@7)
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].loader = require.resolve("babel-loader")

    // Use @babel/preset-react for JSX and env (instead of staged presets)
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.presets = [
      require.resolve("@babel/preset-react"),
      require.resolve("@babel/preset-env"),
    ]

    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins = [
      // Use @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties for class arrow functions
      require.resolve("@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"),

      // Use babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries to remove graphql queries from components when rendering in Storybook
      // While still rendering content from useStaticQuery in development mode
      [
        require.resolve("babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries"),
        {
          stage: config.mode === `development` ? "develop-html" : "build-html",
          staticQueryDir: "page-data/sq/d",
        },
      ],
    ]

    return config
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to **remove** the following lines from the `main.js` file:

```js
 // Use correct react-dom depending on React version.
 if (parseInt(React.version) <= 18) {
   config.externals = ['react-dom/client'];
 }
```